# does gin(go api framework) have IDL method like proto3 or thrift to define a api service?

Tags: api, go, frameworks, idl

does gin have an IDL method like proto3 or thrift to define a api service?

for example , i have an echo api
i want to define it like before
does gin has an IDL tool to generate basic code including field verify input, model generate?

```
message EchoRequest{
  string content = 1;   
}
message EchoData{
 string content = 1;
}
message EchoResponse{
 int status = 1;
 string message = 2;
 EchoData data = 3;   
}
service{
api EchoResponse Echo(EchoRequest )(api.get='/echo')
}
```

Comment: Gin doesn't have that. Protobuffers is a language-agnostic schema to define on-the-wire data serialization. Gin is a web framework written in Go. If you need to define language-agnostic APIs and translate that to web servers in an arbitrary language, you might consider using GraphQL. `99designs/gqlgen` can generate Go handlers from a GQL schema. There are also tutorials to integrate that with Gin.

Comment: ok, it is really nice, this is what i want,  rpc Have many tools to describe rpc interface, the same to api to describe api interface is GraphQL!!! thanks